# How to programmatically get a contact's picture in Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

How can you get a contact's picture from Outlook and save it to a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good, but there's also an alternative:

[**Attachment.GetTemporaryFilePath Method (Outlook)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863306.aspx)

[**Attachment.SaveAsFile Method (Outlook)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359.aspx)

**To retrieve the path.**

```
var attachment = contact.Attachments["ContactPicture.jpg"] as Attachment;
var path = attachment.GetTemporaryFilePath();
```

**To save the file.**

```
var attachment = contact.Attachments["ContactPicture.jpg"] as Attachment;
var path = attachment.SaveAsFile(savePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, if you are trying to grab their picture from their Outlook profile you might want to try Graph API.

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)